# problem with fbconnect api for android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to use fbconnect api in my android app. When i opened the fbconnect file in my workspace it was showing error, but there is no error.

I tried build and clean but no use. Where can i get the fbconnect jar file ?

(I'm using android 2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fbconnect has been depracated and you should use the official Facebook SDK for android which is donwloadable here : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

There is the source code, jar file and sample applications för using facebook in your android application!